# error with npm version : find_dp0' not recognized

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Hei, 
I am running a small node app and when I am running a test on it cames with the error:

```
find_dp0' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Apparently it has to do with a error with the version of [npm] (https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11199) but my npm is on version 6.13.2 and still was the same problem.

Any ideas what can it be?
Thank you

Comment: Thank you @Utkanos.. just pressed enter to fast before adding more tags

Answer (score 0):

You may have different version of Angular CLI installed.
Once you upgrade or downgrade CLI version, it will be disappeared by:

> npm install @angular/cli@[your version]